# How to change UITableviewCell Label Text after UIButton click?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a checkbox (UIButton) and a label in a UITableViewCell. I want to change the label's text (color + strikethrough) when I click on the checkbox.

This is for a Recipe Application. After a cooking step is done, the user can "check" it as done.

This is my current cellForRowAt Function for the tableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == groceryTableView {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: groceryTableViewCell, for: indexPath) as! GroceryItemTableViewCell
        cell.amoutLabel.text = indexPath.item % 2 == 0 ? "50 g" : "500 ml"
        cell.itemLabel.text = indexPath.item % 2 == 0 ? "Cheese" : "Milk"
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cookingStepTableViewCell, for: indexPath) as! CookingStepTableViewCell
        cell.cookingStepDescription.text = indexPath.item % 2 == 0 ? "Test 123..." : "Test 321..."
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
}
```

And this is my Button addTarget Function, which is delegated from the TableViewCell Class to the actual ViewController Class:

```
func cookingStepDone(description: String, isDone: Bool) {
    // if isDone == true
    // label textcolor is gray + strikethrough

    // if isDone == false
    // no change...
}
```

I want that cell.cookingStepDescription label is changed if "isDone" is true (= click on the checkbox)

Comment: When user click on the check box, hold this value in model class or in a global variable. for ex-> isChecked = true.

Reload the table view, and show the value of label value according to isChecked variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the button outlet is taken in cell class. so declare a action method in the cellForRowAtIndexpath i.e like this.

```
 cell.yourDoneBtn?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.cookingStepDone), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Now in your action function:

```
@objc func cookingStepDone(sender: UIButton)
 {
    let location = self.yourTableViewName?.convert(sender.bounds.origin, from:sender)
    let indexPath = self.yourTableViewName?.indexPathForRow(at: location!)
    if let cell = self.yourTableViewName.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as? yourTableViewCell  // i.e groceryTableViewCell or CookingStepTableViewCell
    {
      if isDone == true
      {
        // Set your cell label textcolor to gray + strikethrough 
      }
      else
      {
       // no change
      }
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async
    {
       self.yourTableView.reloadData() // reload your table view 
    }
 }
```

Set your bool value where ever needed.

Comment: Thanks, I did something in that way, just a little bit different, with delegate from TableViewCellClass to the actual UICollectionViewClass:

First I created the Protocol in the TVCellClass:
    protocol CookingStepDelegate {
    func cookingStepDone(sender: UIButton)
}

Then in de TVCellClass:
    @objc func cookingStepCheckBoxButtonTapped() {
        delegate?.cookingStepDone(sender: cookingStepCheckBox)
    }

And in de CollectionViewClass pretty much like your way.

Comment: @Alessandro  yes it can be done through protocols also. Happy Coding !!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using below approach

define an Array, in you cookingStepDone method add `indexPath` to the array and if indexPath already in Array remove it and reload the tableView. and in `cellForRowAtIndexpath`method, check if the Array contains the `indexPath`. if contains make text strikeThrough else make normal.

Answer (score 0):

What if you create a new class whose superclass would be UITableViewCell and inside that class you add in your @IBOutlets (UIButton and UILabel) and an @IBAction (buttonWasTapped)?

Something Like:

```
class RecipeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var myButton : UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var myLabel : UILabel!

    @IBAction func didTouchButton(sender : UIButton)
    {
         myLabel.textColor = UIColor.green;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this code : **RecipeTableViewCell**

```
class RecipeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var myButton : UIButton!
@IBOutlet var myLabel : UILabel!

var buttonClick : (() -> Void)? = nil

override func awakeFromNib() {
    myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTouchButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@IBAction func didTouchButton(sender : UIButton)
{
    if let action = buttonClick {
        action()
    }
}
}
```

In **cellForRowAt**

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell... 
// Your code ...
cell.buttonClick = {
  //access your label and data from here
  cell.yourLbl.text = yourModel[indexPath.row].text
}
```